# Startup apps keep getting reset

Tags: windows, windows-10

Before shutting down Windows, I select in *Settings / Apps / Startup:*

[image: Screenshot with some apps deselected]

After starting Windows again, I see:

[image]

*Why does my selection keep getting reset? Am I missing some save button? Is there a log file to inspect what is going on?*

This is a pretty much a fresh Windows 10 install, about a week old. I realize more and more: Linux you configure, *Windows you fight*

**Update:** I realized that I can permanently disable the apps from *Task Manager / Startup*, and then my selection survives a reboot. Still, my question stands. I expect things to work from *Settings* just fine.

Comment: What version of Windows are you using? Is it a corporate computer with Group Policies applied?

Comment: @CorneliusRoemer *Pro* version, not a corporate computer, no group policies